# Firefox 49.01 rendering \ response time: Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Firefox has become exceptionally slow (sometimes taking 30+ seconds to load pages).  ISP speed has been eliminated as a cause: while loading a page on FF, I have had enough time to go to MS-Edge and open up the same page.  No FF extensions are installed.

Is there a good procedure that can diagnose the top 3 causes of poor FF rendering of web pages?  Diagnostic questions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to diagnose something similar.  Disabling electrolysis in FF seems to have helped, but not all the time.

[Disable Electrolysis](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/22/multi-process-firefox/)

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.